# Typescript: Comparing an ID value in two arrays of objects

Tags: typescript

So, I have two different arrays of objects one object is { id:... } the other object is {getID:..., setID}  if I want to filter down object one to only return id's that exist in the second objects getID but not setID what would be a good solution?

My current hack is basically:

```
forEach(object in OBJECT1) {
    OBJECT2.filter(x => {
      return (x.setID.length === 0 && x.getID === object.id);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
function isOk(obj: any, id: string): boolean {
    return (!obj.setID || obj.setID.length === 0) && id === obj.getID;
}

let ids = OBJECT1.filter(item1 => OBJECT2.some(item2 => isOk(item2, item1.id)));
```